# Deploying after a heroku rollback

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku

My heroku release history looks like -

```
> heroku releases -r production
v587  Rollback to v585  foo@example.co   2016/04/18 16:55:17 -0700 (~ 16m ago)
v586  Deploy b89eb91    foo@example.co   2016/04/18 16:48:28 -0700 (~ 23m ago)
v585  Deploy b6b2ca7    bar@example.co   2016/04/18 15:00:49 -0700 (~ 2h ago)
v584  Deploy c1dce39    bar@example.co   2016/04/18 12:34:35 -0700 (~ 4h ago)
v583  Deploy 91ee10b    bar@example.co   2016/04/15 18:04:24 -0700
```

As you can see, `v586` was a bad release, so I rolled back to `v585`.

Now that I've fixed the issue and merged a fix into `master`, how do I proceed?

Do I simply push the fixed version with `git push production master`, or does it need a `--force`? I asked because it seems like a rollback changes the commit hash that the `HEAD` points to, so didn't know if I had to do anything special to proceed after a `rolllback`

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I have done this many times with a simple "git push heroku master". 
As far as I know, you don't need a --force.

Answer (score 0):

Use `git push heroku --force` to push your local `HEAD.`